# PHP create a hierarchy menu structure

Tags: php, arrays, menu

Basically I have a table in MYSQL

```
Name    ID     Parent  
Bob     321    root  
Sue     32     root  
Boo     393    32  
Geek    72     393  
Sam     312    393  
Tovoc   341    321  
Reese   322    393  
Sheep   811    341
```

I want to create a menu that outputs a menu structure with submenus based on the parent ID

So it should output

```
Bob  
 Tovoc 
  Sheep

Sue
 Boo
 Sam
  Geek
 Reese
```

The child entries are linked with the parent ID and if they have a parent they become a child.
Ultimately it would build a multidimentual array. 
Clues?

Heres what I got so far. It works, but I can't figure out how to increase or reset the margin style properly to get a nice structure view. I have the margin-left increase by 10px in every child elements found, then reset back to 1  if the parent is user

```
isparent(user,1);

  function isparent($Parent,$if=1){

  $stdr = 'SELECT * FROM CraveBins WHERE UserID = '.$_SESSION[CraveUserID].' AND Parent=\''.$Parent.'\' ORDER BY Name ASC';
 $resultMainMenu = mysql_query($stdr) or die('421 '.$stdr.mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows($resultMainMenu)){
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultMainMenu)){
 $if++; 
 echo '<div class="binDir" onclick="setBin(this)" id="BinListUser" style="margin-left:'.(5+($if * 10)).'px" driID="'.$row[ID].'">'.$row['Name'].'</div>'; // echo main menu
 $n =  isparent($row['ID'],$if);
}//end while 
}else{
$if=1;
} // if rows        
}//end function
```

Comment: Clue #1: [Select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29)

Comment: What part are you having a problem with: pulling information from the DB? Forming and appropriate data structure? Outputting HTML? As it stands, this question is too broad.  You should also show what you have tried.

Comment: I think I have  solved it. But now I need to `figure out how to tell the sub menu from within another sub

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your `$if++`. I thought this was your level of indentation. If so: remove the `$if++`, modify the inner `isparent($row['ID'],$if+1)` and you should be fine ... I guess.

Alternatively, move your `$if++` outside the while loop (before ;o)

Also: you don't need `mysql_num_rows(...)`, I believe. Just start fetching, and it'll return nothing if it's finished. Also, don't use mysql_*, use mysqli or pdo.

If your `$if` was meant to count the children, just call it `$n`, don't mix depth and count.